# react setState doesnt work neither its callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

when i call this.setState in my code it seems to do nothing at all

```
this.setState({array:pre.array},()=>{console.log("setState")})
```

i can't even see the log from the call back function here is my code

```
class Watch extends React.Component{
    constructor(pre) {
        super(pre);

        this.state = { color: "green" }

        this.setState(() => {
            return {array:newarray}
        }, console.log("setState works"))
```

p.s:i have tried to put `setState` in `onClick` function, in `componentDidMount(),componentDidUpdate()` still dosent work with no error

Comment: Works fine: https://codesandbox.io/s/z3jj4qk02x The problem is in code you're not showing us.

Comment: Do console.log after some timeout. That will work fine.

Comment: but how could it be in the code that does not allow a setstate function to start its not in a condition or anything its just there in constructor at the very last

Comment: yes if i do console.log not in the callback it does show up but the state does not change

Comment: I am not sure if this.setState takes in function as argument. it rather takes an argument of object type . `this.setState({array: newArray})`

Comment: @GrinningTrout As you can see from the live code example I posted, it works perfectly fine. I could add a live React example in a stack overflow answer that also shows that `this.setState()` works perfectly fine. But if you want help with this, you need to show us the rest of your code.

Comment: @ShubhamJain It does. It can do both. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Comment: setState works fine. Can you share your complete code? @GrinningTrout

Comment: i have found the problem but don't know how to solve it my problem is the when i do the callback as a function it dose not work but if i do it like this (setState(({array:somearray}),console.log("state works")) it works just fine can anyone help me with that i want to do a multi thinks in the callback but cant without the function in the callback

Answer (score 1):

It seems like when using setState callback system, the first parameter (updater) needed to be in the form of a function as well. So you can try something like:

```
  onEditText=(value)=>{
    this.setState((state, props)=>{
      return {text: value}
    }, this.onTextEdited);
  }

  onTextEdited=()=>{
    //this will be printed with the updated value
    console.log('onTextEdited', this.state.text)
  }
```

See if this helps.